# How to parse the product info out from a netsted JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I can get the product lists from an API, the results is like this:

```
{
    "request": 
            {
                "uri":"xxxxx",
                "time":"xxxx"
            }
    "response":
            {
                "result":
                        {
                            "productA": 
                                    {
                                        "info1":"xxx",
                                        "info2":"xxx"
                                        "info3":"xxx"
                                    },
                            "productB":
                                    {
                                        "info1":"xxx",
                                        "info2":"xxx",
                                        "info3":"xxx"
                                    }
                        },
                "otherinfo":
                        {
                            "xxxx":"xxxx"
                        },
                "error":
                        {
                            "xxxx":"xxxx"
                        }

            }
}
```

I am using Java, and I want to get the products info from the "result" node, for every product, I need to get:
1. the product names(like productA, productB,etc.)
2. the product's properties(like info1,info2,info3)
how could I get these information using Jackson?

Comment: did you try anything? any code to show?

Comment: yeah，I tried，the problem is the number of products is not a fixed, and they are not an array value of "results" node

Comment: I would suggest fixing the API that returns you this data if you'd like a list of products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Parse the whole json with Jackson.
2. Get a map back.
3. Access nested maps for any information you need.

Comment: the problem is the number of products is not a fixed, and they are not an array value of "results" node

Comment: `Map` has the `values()` method, which will return a list of all values in the `response.result` map. They will be your products. Or `keySet` for a set of all keys, product names in your case.

Comment: I can use JsonNode,path("result") method to get the "result" node, and then ,How could I convert the child node of "result" into object?